# Report query form's parameters are disabled

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

I've create Query then develope report that using this query then I created Menu Item for the report, but the issue is when I'm running the report from the menu item the criteria fields are locked, why? Am I missing something here?

[image: Query Run]

[image: locked fields]

Answer (score 1):

Check whether the query allows adding fields.

Comment: All DataSource AllowAdd = All Fields